# Switch statement in Javascript with variable comparison

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I've found a great count up timer on-line, but I need a timer that will show time till a certain date, and once that date-time has past, it'll show how long it's been since that date-time.

I've tried to add a switch statement, but I get all zero's.

The statement has to change depending on if the count to/from date has passed.

Here's the entire webpage

```
    <html>
    <head>
 <title>Orders with Approvals Received</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="150">
<script>
/*
 * Basic Count Up from Date and Time
 * Author: @mrwigster / https://guwii.com/bytes/count-date-time-javascript/
 */
window.onload = function() {
  // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container
  countUpFromTime("Feb 6, 2020 15:00:00", 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
};
function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
  countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
  var now = new Date(),
      countFrom = new Date(countFrom),

      timeDifference = now < countup1 ? (countFrom - now): (now - countFrom);
  //  timeDifference = (now - countFrom); // Count Up
   //  timeDifference = (countFrom - now); //Count Down

    var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
      secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

  days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
  hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  secs = Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('seconds')[0].innerHTML = secs;

  clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
  countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function(){ countUpFromTime(countFrom, id); }, 1000);
}

</script>
<style>
body {margin:0;
width: 322px;
height: 192px;
}
.caption
    {
        background-color:BLUE;
        color:white;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:white;
        text-align:center;
    }
.countup {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.countup .timeel {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px;
  background: #151515;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.countup span[class*="timeRef"] {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: #e8c152;
  color: black;
}

</style>
    </head>
<body>
   <thead>
    <div class="caption">
    <caption>1_Arthur20 Ended</caption>
    </div>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
<div class="countup" id="countup1">
  <span class="timeel days">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefDays">D</span>
  <span class="timeel hours">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefHours">H</span>
  <span class="timeel minutes">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefMinutes">M</span>
  <span class="timeel seconds">00</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefSeconds">S</span>
</div>
<div class="countup" id="countup1">
  <span class="timeel days">2</span>
  <span class="timeel timeRefDays">Open</span>
  <span class="timeel hours">502</span>
 <span class="timeel timeRefHours">Total</span>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate any help that you could give. 
Thanks,

Edit: I added the line as palash suggested, but one the time has passed it gives me an extra 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute. So when it's counting down it works great, once it hits all zeros, I get the extra time on the count up. I thought it might be because of timezone, but if I substitute the count up code it works fine. Not certain what's going on with it.

Thanks to everyone that commented.

Comment: If you look closely at your brackets, you will see the switch statement only contains one case.  This is an example of why proper code indentation is important.

Comment: switch statement with comparisons is just a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned, make sure you have no closing brackets inside your `case` blocks, only at the end of the switch statement.

```
switch (true) {
  case now <= countUpFromTime:
    timeDifference = (countFrom - now);
    break;
  case now > countUpFromTime:
    timeDifference = (now - countFrom);
    break;
  default:
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `switch` statement in this scenario, you can use [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) here like:

```
timeDifference = now <= countUpFromTime ? (countFrom - now) : (now - countFrom);
```

Comment: palash, I added the line as you suggested: